# How to download beta versions of Vmware fusion

Tags: vmware, macosx, vmware-workstation, vmware-player, vmware-fusion

How can I download beta versions of Vmware fusion for Mac?

The current version has a lot of bugs with macOS big sur
I searched the internet a lot but nothing was found.

Comment: Sorry I do not see how that is a Ubuntu question.

Comment: the problems are with ubuntu on macOS big sur, beta versions fix this but how to get it?

Comment: I agree: this has nothing to do with Ubuntu. We only have one -stable- version and if that one has bugs file bug reports. Ubuntu does not use beta versions so there are none in the repositories so if you want one you need to search for them and hope they supply you with a PPA.

Comment: I am beta version of VMware not ubuntu, my vm can't connect to internet, some suggest changing the NAT but IDK how to do that.